# Десериализация Json с#. Определение модели для десериализации. Что не так?

Tags: c#, json

```
namespace ParseJson
{
    public class GlobalType
    {
        [JsonProperty("Q")]
        public string ClassType { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("D")]
        public Dictionary<string, List<Houses>> HouseModel { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<string, List<Users>> UserModel { get; set; }
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return string.Format(ClassType);
        }

    }

    public class Houses
    {
        [JsonProperty("name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("address")]
        public string Address { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("type")]
        public int Type { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("flors")]
        public int Flors { get; set; }
    }
    public class Users
    {
        [JsonProperty("name")]
        public string name { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("login")]
        public string login { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("group")]
        public int group { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("phones")]
        public List<Phones> phone { get; set; }
    }
    public class Phones
    {
        [JsonProperty("id")]
        public string id { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("value")]
        public string value { get; set; }

    }
}
{
    "Q": "HOUSES",    
    "D": 
    {        
        "items": 
        [
            {
                "name": "Дом Ивана",
                "address": "г. Казань, Кремлевская 1",
                "type": 1,
                "flors": 2
            },
            {
                "name": "Дом Ирины",
                "address": "г. Казань, Кремлевская 2",
                "type": 2,
                "flors": 1
            },
            {
                "name": "Вотчина Деда мороза",
                "address": "Россия, Великий устюг, Дедо морозовская 1",
                "type": 3,
                "flors": 2
            }
        ]
    }

}
{
    "Q": "USERS",    
    "D": 
    {        
        "items": 
        [
            {
                "name": "Иван",
                "login": "Ivan",
                "group": 1,
                "phones": [
                    {
                        "id": 1,
                        "value": "+791234567890"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 2,
                        "value": "+7843952000000"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "Ирина",
                "login": "Irina",
                "group": 2,
                "phones": []
            },
            {
                "name": "Дед Мороз",
                "login": "dead_moroz",
                "group": 1,
                "phones": [
                    {
                        "id": 1,
                        "value": "+71234567890"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }

}
```

Comment: Вам сюда закиньте свой JSON  и посмотрите https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Comment: Ваша проблема в том, что вы пытаетесь использовать 1 класс для двух разных по сути JSON файлов. Вот у вас два свойства: `public Dictionary<string, List<Houses>> HouseModel { get; set; }` и `public Dictionary<string, List<Users>> UserModel { get; set; }`, что вы ожидаете тут получить? И то и то сразу? Просто так не выйдет. Если же взять один JSON (как я понял их тут 2, если нет - у вас ошибка в JSON)  и десериализовать, то ваша модель без труда справиться с этим. Если все же надо 2 JSON записать в 1 класс, то нужен конвертер, который будет сверять `Q` и по его основе действовать.